# How to handle the exception that not found remote server?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone-8

Now I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 app that using Azure service

But I got an exception as follow:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
Stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at CaptWP.CAPTService.Service1Client.Service1ClientChannel.EndgetRandomID(IAsyncResult result)
   at CaptWP.CAPTService.Service1Client.CaptWP.CAPTService.IService1.EndgetRandomID(IAsyncResult result)
   at CaptWP.CAPTService.Service1Client.OnEndgetRandomID(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

After checked the Azure server, I found Azure stop the service due to insufficient account balance.

But how to solve the problem in client? Maybe sometime the server is unavailable or disconnect. Almost all actions need to get response from server in my app, so I must to solve this problem for application instability.

I want to add `try....catch....` at each action to communicate to server, but the reference methods in Windows Phone 8 is asynchronous

```
service.getRandomIDAsync();

private void service_getRandomIDCompleted(object sender, CAPTService.getRandomIDCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   string id = e.Result.ToString();
}
```

How to catch exception? Also I have to add so many `try..catch` block in my code. So I want to add it in the **`Reference.cs`** in Service References

Any one can provide a solution? or better way?

Comment: Right now you are getting "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." And, you want to go to the actual exception?

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal, Of course, I just want to solve the problem to prevent the program crashes. And now my server is working well, but probably sometime the server is unavailable or disconnect, this exception occurs.

Comment: With the Windows Phone, very often (due to some legacy cruft) any HTTP error code is returned as "NotFound" - you need to examine in the debugger the inner exception and other properties (or even cast to Http*) in order to learn more about the failure. This could also be an HTTP 500, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Classes that should be used azure expected to handle exceptions, not the native VisualStudio

Regards.